# comparable.vo contains library Top.comparable and not library comparable

Tags: coq

I am very new to Coq.

In our project, we switched to using the `coq_makefile` utility and came across the following problem.

Stepping through a proof script would result in this error:

```
Require Import comparable.

Error:
The file /Users/ayman/open-source/regex-reexamined-coq/comparable.vo contains library
Top.comparable and not library comparable
```

Our `_CoqProject` file is very simple (maybe that is the problem), it just lists all the files in the project https://github.com/awalterschulze/regex-reexamined-coq/blob/2c865aecc00276e0a926c1729cc35553c1cc6767/_CoqProject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coq libraries have a logical path. For example, files from the standard library all have a logical path starting with `Coq`. In your case, you did not specify anything about the logical path, so Coq arbitrarily puts the compiled files into a path starting with `Top`. Later, when trying to load the file, Coq compares the logical path `Top` to the physical path `.` and complains about the discrepancy.

The simplest fix is to add the following line to your `_CoqProject` file: `-R . Top`. Option `-R` maps a physical path (here `.`) to a logical path (here `Top`), which will fix the discrepancy.

But `Top` is a poor name for a library, so you should replace it with something else. Moreover, that name will serve as the installation path for your library, so choose a meaningful name (e.g., `RegexDerivatives`), as that is the name users will be using.

Comment: Thank you! That worked and the explaination was really useful.